# Finding if the leafs of an unsorted binary tree have the maximum values on their branch

Tags: tree, binary-tree, pascal

Given is an unsorted binary tree containing positive integers. I am supposed to write a function, which checks if every leaf in the tree has the biggest on the branch leading to it. I am allowed to assume that the input tree is at least 2 nodes big.  The function receives as input a pointer to the root of the tree and a number. This number is to be calculated by the function and is to be the maximum value on the branch. The function is recursive function an I am using Pascal.

For some reason my function keeps returning only false. What am I doing wrong?

```
function leafsMax ( root : tRefBinBaum; branchMax : tNatZahl) : Boolean;

var
left,
right : boolean;  

begin
       {stop condition for my function, we have reached a leaf}  
       if (root^.left = nil) and (root^.right = nil) then
       begin
          if root^.value > branchMax then
             leafsMax := true
          else
            leafsMax := false;
       end;

       {calculate the new maximum}  
       if branchMax < root^.value then 
            branchMax := root^.value;

       {check the left side}
       if root.left <> nil then 
       begin
         left := leafsMax(root.left, branchMax);
       end;

       {check the right side}
       if root.right <> nil then 
       begin
         right := leafsMax(root.right, branchMax);
       end;

       leafsMax := left and right;

end;
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, you are failing to initialise your `left` and `right` local vars fully - both will have random values unless the assignments to them execute.  Set them both to `False` at the start of your procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried that as well with initializing. I have found out that the function returns the value of the initialization. I just can't see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Hmmm. You evaluate the entire thing each time even though "if left=nil and right=nil" looks like the finish. Maybe a simple exit in that block will do because despite the fact you are "finished" you evaluate the whole thing and then at the last you re-evaluate leafsMax which is apparently always false?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am doing something wrong that is sure. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Without knowing your data, it's hard to be sure, but surely the final line is wrong - or in other words, I doubt very much whether *both* left and right are true. If one of them is false, the the function's result will be false.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if returning Boolean is a good idea; a better one would be to return a pointer to the actual node.

It makes the decision to whether the leaf on left-hand side of  the branch has a greater value than the leaf on right-hand side of the branch.

If you still need a Boolean answer, you can always check whether leafsMax() has returned nil (i.e. False).

ANd, if it's not nil, then you can read the returned node's value to see what the actual max value is.

See the code below.

```
function leafsMax(ANode: PRecord; AMax: TValue): PRecord;
var
  Left1: PRecord;  
  Right1: PRecord;  
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (ANode^.Left = nil) and (ANode^.Right = nil) then begin
   if ANode^.Value > AMax then Result := ANode;
  end;

  if Result = nil then begin
   Left1 := nil;
   Right1 := nil;

   if ANode^.Value > AMax then AMax := ANode^.Value;
   if ANode.Left <> nil then Left1 := leafsMax(ANode.Left, AMax);
   if ANode.Right <> nil then Right1 := leafsMax(ANode.Right, AMax);

   if (Left1 <> nil) and (Right1 = nil) then Result := Left1
   else if (Left1 = nil) and (Right1 <> nil) then Result := Right1
   else if (Left1 <> nil) and (Right1 <> nil) then begin
     if Left1.Value > Right1.Value then Result := Left1
     else if Right1.Value > Left1.Value then Result := Right1
     else Result := Left1; {any one would do.}
   end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time and writing this code.